# Images not loading properly on pygame

Tags: python

I'm making a hangman game using pygame. Everything is done except my images aren't cycling through properly.

images are in the same directory as main.py and I've checked the names to make sure they match multiple times(they do). I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem, so I was hoping for some help? Hopefully I'm just missing something obvious here.

Image loading code:
`

```
# Load images.
images = []
for i in range(7):
    image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f"Hangman{i}.png")
    image = pygame.image.load("Hangman" + str(i) + ".png")  # Adjusted the filenames
    images.append(image)
```

Full code:

```
import sys
import os
import math
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import QUIT

# Sets up display.
pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 1000))
pygame.display.set_caption("Vancouver Canucks Hangman")

# Fonts.
letterfont = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 32)
wordfont = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 36)

# Game variables.
status = 0
guessed = []
words = [
    "ELIAS PETTERSSON", "J.T MILLER", "QUINN HUGHES", "BROCK BOESER",
    "FILIP HRONEK", "THATCHER DEMKO", "CASEY DESMITH", "SAM LAFFERTY",
    "CONOR GARLAND", "DAKOTA JOSHUA", "ANDREI KUZMENKO", "IAN COLE", "TYLER MYERS",
    "NIKITA ZADOROV", "ROBERTO LUONGO", "HENRIK SEDIN", "DANIEL SEDIN", "ALEX BURROWS",
    "MARKUS NASLUND", "KIRK MCLEAN", "TREVOR LINDEN", "PAVEL BURE",
    "GINO ODJICK", "TODD BERTUZZI", "STAN SMYL", "ORLAND KURTENBACH",
    "THOMAS GRADIN", "BO HORVAT", "RYAN KESSLER"
]
word = random.choice(words).upper()  # Ensure the word is in uppercase.
status = 0
# Button variables.
radius = 20
gap = 15
letters = []
startx = round((1600 - (radius * 2 + gap) * 13) / 2)
starty = 650 
A = 65
for i in range(26):
    x = startx + gap * 2 + ((radius * 2 + gap) * (i % 13))
    y = starty + ((i // 13) * (gap + radius * 2))
    letters.append([x, y, chr(A + i), True])  # Puts letters on buttons.

# Colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)

# Load images.
images = []
for i in range(7):
    image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f"Hangman{i}.png")
    image = pygame.image.load("Hangman" + str(i) + ".png")  # Adjusted the filenames
    images.append(image)
    


# Drawing function.
def draw():
    display.fill(white)
    display.blit(images[status], (150, 100))

    # Draw word with spaces between letters.
    spaced_word = ""
    for letter in word:
        if letter in guessed:
            spaced_word += letter + " "
        elif letter == " ":
            spaced_word += "  "
        else:
            spaced_word += "_ "
    text = wordfont.render(spaced_word, 1, black)
    display.blit(text, (470, 500))

    # Draw buttons.
    for letter in letters:
        x, y, ltr, visible = letter
        if visible:
            pygame.draw.circle(display, blue, (x, y), radius, 3) # Line of code that actually draws the buttons.
            text = letterfont.render(ltr, 1, blue) # Button visuals like colour.
            display.blit(text,
                         (x - text.get_width() / 2, y - text.get_height() / 2)) 

    pygame.display.update() # Updates display.

# Set up game loop.
incorrectguess = 0
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Main game loop
run = True


def display_message(message, HEIGHT): # Function to display message.
    global incorrectguess
    pygame.time.delay(1000)
    display.fill(white)
    text = wordfont.render(message, 1, black)
    display.blit(text, (display.get_width()/2 - text.get_width()/2, HEIGHT/2 - text.get_height()/2))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(3000)

# Main gameplay loop.
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            m_x, m_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for letter in letters: # Loop that makes sure the letter buttons work.
                x, y, ltr, visible = letter
                if visible:
                    dis = math.sqrt((x - m_x) ** 2 + (y - m_y) ** 2)
                    if dis < radius:
                        letter[3] = False  # Set button visibility to False when clicked
                        guessed.append(ltr)
                        if ltr not in word: # Keeps track of wrong guesses.
                            incorrectguess += 1
                            

    draw()
    pygame.display.update()

    if incorrectguess >= 6:
        status = 6  # Sets the right image.
        draw() # Draws the final image.
        pygame.display.update() # Updates final image.
        display_message("YOU LOSE!", 1000) # Displays lose message.
        run = False # Ends game.

    # Check win condition
    won = all(letter in guessed or letter == ' ' for letter in word)

    if won:
        # Display win screen
        display.fill(blue)
        text = wordfont.render("YOU WON!", 1, white)
        display.blit(text, (display.get_width() // 2 - text.get_width() // 2,
                            display.get_height() // 2 - text.get_height() // 2))
        pygame.display.update()

        # Delay the closing of the window after winning
        pygame.time.delay(3000)
        run = False

    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score -1):

You are creating an `image_path` variable but not using it in your code. Try changing your code to this :

```
images = []
for i in range(7):
    image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f"Hangman{i}.png")
    image = pygame.image.load(image_path) 
    images.append(image)
```

Comment: The images still aren't loading. I guess deliberately wrong letters and they aren't cycling through.